# c# how to change font size/style when using StreamWriter

Tags: c#

```
StreamWriter SW;
            SW = File.CreateText("c:\\abc.odt");
            SW.WriteLine("firstline\nTsecondline\nThird line");
```

When I check the file in the c: directory , It opens up with default font size/style .. any idea how to change them

Comment: Fon't has nothing to do with a stream of char

Comment: StreamWriter has nothing to do with styles and fonts. The thing it is streaming may have style and font information in it but it has nothing to do with the StreamWriter itself.

Comment: Is there any other way where i can insert a text with the required font size in an odt file . ?

Comment: You have to look for some library to allow you to save odt files.

Comment: HI felice .. do you have any suggestions for the same ?

Answer (score 7):

You are saving a text file, so there is no font information on it. If you want to save rich text use a proper file format, as for example [rtf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). Obviously to save such a file a plain stream writer is no more enought, so you probably have to explain better what you want to do.

Comment: I have a form , that has text boxes . I intend to have each textboxes test to be inserted into an ODT file with different font sizes and different font styles